# Pandas - NameError: name 'df2' is not defined

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

For a current project, I am running a number of iterations of a Pandas DataFrame and plan to print the variable `df2`.

When calling the line `print(df2)`, I am however getting the error `NameError: name 'df2' is not defined`. I have already been checking for solutions but have not found anything yet. Is there any smart tweak to make this run?

The corresponding code section looks like this:

```
# Open the file to write to
with open('sp500-1.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)

    # Write headers
    writer.writerow(["Section", "TFI"])

    # Loop over the JSON objects
    for i in ['txt_pro','txt_con','txt_adviceMgmt','txt_main']:

        # Loop over the common words inside the JSON object
        common_words = get_top_n_bigram_Group2(df[i], 500)
        for word in common_words:

            # Print and write row.
            print(df2)
            writer.writerow([df2])
```

And the code that defines `df2` is as follows:

```
def get_top_n_bigram_Group2(corpus, n=None):
    # settings that you use for count vectorizer will go here
    tfidf_vectorizer=TfidfVectorizer(ngram_range=(2, 2), stop_words='english', use_idf=True).fit(corpus)

    # just send in all your docs here
    tfidf_vectorizer_vectors=tfidf_vectorizer.fit_transform(corpus)

    # get the first vector out (for the first document)
    first_vector_tfidfvectorizer=tfidf_vectorizer_vectors[0]

    # place tf-idf values in a pandas data frame
    df1 = pd.DataFrame(first_vector_tfidfvectorizer.T.todense(), index=tfidf_vectorizer.get_feature_names(), columns=["tfidf"])
    df2 = df1.sort_values(by=["tfidf"],ascending=False)

    return df2
```

Comment: You are not actually defining `df2` in the global scope (i.e., outside of the function `get_top_n_bigram_Group2`). You name the output of `get_top_n_bigram_Group2` `common_words`, so you should use `print(common_words)`. The name `df2` only exists within the function.

Comment: Thanks for the great input. If I understand things correctly, `common_words` will in this case yield the `df2` variable that has been defined in `def get_top_n_bigram_Group2`

Comment: also note that dataframes have a `.to_csv` method that will probably make your life much easier

Comment: Thanks, let me see to integrate that. For now the code did only print the right output in the terminal but has not written the lines in the .csv file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happens because df2 is defined inside your function and it obeys [python scope of variables](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-scope-of-variables/), so it exists only inside your function definition.

Since you return it and pass another name to it:

```
common_words = get_top_n_bigram_Group2(df[i], 500)
```

So you **return** *df2* value and pass it as *common_words*

And then you are iterating over it:

```
for word in common_words:
```

Therefore you should use *word*, instead of *df2* in your printing and writerow functions.

Answer (score 1):

Hey this is just a simple question.
See a function returns a variable but it returns to the variable where it is called.

```
# Open the file to write to
  with open('sp500-1.csv', 'w', newline='') as file:
writer = csv.writer(file)

# Write headers
writer.writerow(["Section", "TFI"])

# Loop over the JSON objects
for i in ['txt_pro','txt_con','txt_adviceMgmt','txt_main']:

    # Loop over the common words inside the JSON object
    common_words = get_top_n_bigram_Group2(df[i], 500)
    for word in common_words:

        # Print and write row.
        print(common_words)
        writer.writerow([word])
```

Comment: where common_words will give you then whole object & word will give you a record

Comment: Thanks, that makes the code run through. It however does not write any of the variables into the .csv file (output I receive is 4 x `tfidf`).

Comment: Yeah, maybe you just have to tweak your function so that it returns the expected result. Thanks a lot for accepting

Answer (score 0):

Well, when you ran `get_top_n_bigram_Group2`, you stored `df2` into `common_words`.